# Using browser to run PHP file outside www directory - get public website "page not found" instead

Tags: vps, wordpress

I have a virtual private server on which I run two different WordPress websites.

I am now trying to install SuiteCRM on the same server. Following the SuiteCRM [instructions](https://docs.suitecrm.com/admin/installation-guide/downloading-installing/), I've unzipped SuiteCRM files to a folder (/opt/SuiteCRM-7.11.18/) on the server. I'm now supposed to open a browser and enter:

```
http://<yourServer>/<yourSuiteCRMDirectory>/install.php
```

Which I believe in my case is:

```
http://<my server's IP address>/opt/SuiteCRM-7.11.18/install.php
```

However, the browser simply loads a "page not found" page from one of my 2 public websites. Any ideas what needs to happen to stop my public website machinery from interfering with this request? Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be missing the whole part where you configure your webserver to look at the new location outside www directory. The documentation does not mention this because it doesn't mention installing the application outside of the already configured www directory either (from what I saw at a quick glance)

Comment: What yoonix is trying to say, is that the web server must be configured to recognize and incorporate the new structure.  By design, access to any file outside the knowledge of the web server, is (and must remain) not possible, if only for security reasons. If your web server  is apache, have a look at the /etc/apache2 folder's configuration files

Answer (score 0):

As @yoonix and @Dennis pointed out, my web server (apache2) is configured to only allow public access to certain folders on the server. /opt is not one of them, but /var/www is.

Rather than change Apache2 configuration, I moved the SuiteCRM folder into /var/www/. Then I was able to get the install.php file to load using this in my browser:

```
https://<my website domain>/SuiteCRM-7.11.18/install.php
```